# Minimum of quadratic program

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

Given a symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and vectors $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $c \in [0,\infty)^n$ is there a closed-form solution of the following quadratic program?

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x^T A x + b^T x\\ \text{subject to} & c^T x = 1 \\ & x_{i} \ge 0\end{array}$$

Note that $A$ is not necessarily positive-definite.

If not, how can I solve this efficiently? Are there specific algorithms?

Comment: If $A$ is not positive definite, then there is no guarantee that this minimum exists.

Comment: @Ben Grossmann You are right, I forgot to add that $c\ge 0$ which enforces boundedness of all $x$

Answer (score 0):

Closed form under some hypothesis. Supposing $A$ invertible and also $\frac 12x^TA x+b^Tx,\ \text{s. t.}\ \ c^Tx=1$ (without the condition $x\ge 0$)

Considering the lagrangian

$$
L = \frac 12x^TA x+b^Tx-\lambda(c^Tx-1)
$$

the stationary points are the solution for

$$
\cases{x^T A+b^T-\lambda c^T = 0\\
c^Tx - 1 = 0}
$$

If $A$ is invertible

$$
x = \lambda A^{-T}c-A^{-T}b
$$

substituting into the restriction

$$
\lambda c^TA^{-T}c-c^{T}A^{-T}b=1
$$

so

$$
\lambda = 1-\frac{c^{T}A^{-T}b}{c^TA^{-T}c}
$$

and finally

$$
x = \left(1-\frac{c^{T}A^{-T}b}{c^TA^{-T}c}\right)A^{-T}c-A^{-T}b
$$

Comment: @Cesaro Thanks, but do you know how we can solve it for $x\ge0$ ?

Comment: Depending on $b$ in some circumstances, the condition $x\ge 0$ can be assured but in the general case I don't believe it is possible a closed form answer.